# What authentication does MVC Authenticate rely on?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization

I like MVC's security attribute `[Authorize]` for authorization and authentication.  You can pass in roles or usernames, and complement it with `[AllowAnonymous]`.  Great.

The thing is: how does MVC know if my user is logged in, or what roles they are in?  Is there a way to tell it how I'm authenticating?  Or does it assume that I'm using ASP.NET Identity?  Or something else?

I know someone's going to say this is a stupid question, but honestly, I've looked all over documentation and everywhere else and this just isn't specified.

Comment: by default uses the Membership class. Authentication mode is defeined in the Web.Config, tag is "authentication" in the <system.web> section.

Comment: Thank you.  You should have posted that as an answer.

Comment: ok, I'll promote it as an answer and you can mark it as such if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC security is loosely coupled with the actual security implementation. This means that it really doesn't matter if you are using Windows authentication (based on windows users), Forms authentication (based on cookies), or some other brew of authentication.

If you take a look at the [source code for AuthorizeAttribute](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs#L84) you can see that all it does is check whether the [IIdentity.IsAuthenticated property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity.isauthenticated(v=vs.110).aspx) is true to determine whether the user is logged in, and also checks the IPrincipal interface to check the user and/or roles.

So in short, the only requirement for the security mechanism is for it to implement IPrincipal and IIdentity and to set those interfaces in the the [Application_BeginRequest event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) (for stateless security) or [Application_AcquireRequestState event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.acquirerequeststate(v=vs.110).aspx) (if using session state for security) in Global.asax.

Comment: Thanks for all this information, this has really helped too.  Unfortunately I can only accept one answer as "the" answer, but you and user1666620 both really helped on this one.

Comment: What am I setting my interfaces equal to in Application_AcquireRequestState in Global.asax?  I have my custom User class inheriting those interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Originally posted this as a comment, but seems to have been the answer:

By default the Membership class is used. Authentication mode is defined in the Web.Config, tag is "authentication" in the `<system.web>` section.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET in particular, it is common to put ASPX pages in a folder under the control of a custom **web.config** file that redirects unauthenticated users to a predefined login page.